# Aligning texts and drawings in beamer

Tags: beamer, horizontal-alignment

I am making a presentation using beamer for the first time. Please see the following code.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
{
  \usetheme{Warsaw}
  \setbeamercovered{transparent}
}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{epic}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
\section{}
\subsection{}
\begin{frame}
\setlength{\unitlength}{0.8cm}
\begin{picture}(12,4)
\put(0,-1){\vector(0,1){5}}
\put(0,-1){\vector(1,0){5}}
\put(0.7,-0.5){\line(1,1){4}}
\put(0.5,3.5){\line(6,-5){4.5}}
\put(0,1.6){\line(1,0){2.8}}
\dashline{0.2}(0,3)(4.2,3)
\put(-0.6,2.8){$e_1$}
\end{picture}
Hello! Here is the text. This is an additional sentence added to the text to see the output.
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

You can use sharelatex to see the output. The drawing is fine. But I want the text to aligned on the right of the picture. Any suggestions on how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can distribute figure and text in two columns:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
{
  \usetheme{Warsaw}
  \setbeamercovered{transparent}
}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{epic}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
\section{}
\subsection{}
\begin{frame}

\begin{columns}[onlytextwidth]
\column[T]{.5\linewidth}
\setlength{\unitlength}{0.8cm}
\begin{picture}(12,4)
\put(0,-1){\vector(0,1){5}}
\put(0,-1){\vector(1,0){5}}
\put(0.7,-0.5){\line(1,1){4}}
\put(0.5,3.5){\line(6,-5){4.5}}
\put(0,1.6){\line(1,0){2.8}}
\dashline{0.2}(0,3)(4.2,3)
\put(-0.6,2.8){$e_1$}
\end{picture}
\column[T]{.5\linewidth}
Hello! Here is the text. This is an additional sentence added to the text to see the output.
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```